# Adding data into map using type alias, alias template

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, set, using

I am new to C++.  I am not able to understand this code snippet's logic. Could some help me understand this and help me with the concept loading data into the map using the function defined. Problem Explanation : Param1 refers to variables A and B and Param2 refers to B and C.

```
class VariableInformation
{
using ParameterNameSet = std::set<std::string>;
using VariableReferences = std::map<std::string, ParameterNameSet>;
VariableReferences m_referencesToVariables;

public:
void addReferenceToVariable(std::string parameterName, std::string variableName)    
{
    m_referencesToVariables[variableName].insert(parameterName);
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking at is the new c++11 way of doing typedef. so, a statement like:

```
using ParameterNameSet = std::set<std::string>;
```

is equivalent to this:

```
typedef std::set<std::string> ParameterNameSet;
```

i know a lot of engineers prefer the new syntax. personally, i am old school. i like the typedef way. to each, their own.

as for what the code does, it defines a map of sets:

```
VariableReferences m_referencesToVariables;
```

it then uses the overloaded std::map::operator [] to either access an existing element, or insert one if not there (together with an empty set). the std::map::operator [] returns a reference to it's value (the set) which is then used to insert into. hope this helps.